# 6 degree to 3 degree Transverse Mercator transformation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, utm

I am looking to plot coordinates that were given to me but I am having some issues projections.

I currently have my data projected to NAD83 MTM 1, but the coordinates that were given to me are based in a 51 Degree West longitude of the 6 Degree Transverse Mercator Projection, NAD 83.

Using ArcGIS, what projection would I use to do the transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MTM 1 coordinate system for Newfoundland (my guess) is found in he projected coordinate systems section, national grids then Canada and select your MTM zone.  You can project these data into a UTM zone 22 keeping the same NAD83 datum between the systems

[image: UTM zones]

[image: MTM zones]